# Are rewrite conditions required?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have the following in my .htaccess file and it works perfectly on XAMPP, but does not work on my web host:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options All -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine   on
    RewriteRule ^content/tagged/(\w+)/?$ content.html?tagged=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
    RewriteRule !.*\.html$ %{REQUEST_URI}.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

On XAMPP all of the rules work, on the host only the second rule works. The first rule gives me a 404 error. Do I need to add conditions for the first rule?

EDIT: The first rule should handle example.com/content/tagged/foo (for content.html?tagged=foo), but does not. The second rule successfully handles example.com/content (for content.html).

EDIT: removed `RewriteBase` from code above to more accurately reflect what I am using.

Comment: I commented out the lines and the second set of conditions and the rule works. I have also sent a request to the hosting company because I do not see the mod when running `php_info()` @anubhava

Comment: @anubhava I have confirmed mod_rewrite is working on the host now, but still not honoring the first rule. I have removed `RewriteBase` and still no joy.

Comment: I suspect you already did, but ensure it's behaving the same way in multiple browsers or incognito/private windows. It's way too easy to get a browser to hang onto some previously cached redirect and make it difficult to debug.

Comment: No redirect @anubhava and you're right, content.html is now in the root as opposed to the issue I had before.

Comment: Thanks for the reminder @MichaelBerkowski, and I have made sure :)

Comment: Yes, it is in the document root and the second rule works.

Comment: `garbage` added to top of htaccess caused the 500, as expected. I have to step away for a bit (drat!) but I'll check back in a little while.

Comment: Adding `RewriteLog...` or the newer `LogLevel...` causes a 500 error. :-/

Comment: `RewriteLog` doesn't work from .htaccess. It has to be enabled in Apache server config.

Comment: I'll have to work with the host on that @anubhava as I do not have access to the Apache configs. I may have to find a different host.

Comment: Logging enabled @anubhava and there is othing in the log when I get the 404 error. If I a make a change, say [NC] to [NCasdf], I do get an error for that.

Comment: Thanks @anubhava - I am chatting with the host provider now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It would appear that Apache or mod_rewrite versions are not PCRE compatible. When I changed `(\w+)` into `([a-z]+)` the rewrite started working. I'll have to avoid the regex shortcuts and instead use their longer equivalents.

EDIT: Modified the html to include `<base href="/" />` and then additional problems (related to CSS and included images) went away. Also modified localhost such that the testing is going on in the `DocumentRoot`

NOTE: The host in this case was unaware they had a problem with PCRE compatible regex and is checking into the issue.

Comment: No that cannot be. You can check official docs and `\w+` is well supported unless you are running something other than Apache.

Comment: I'll have to dig deeper @anubhava, as I am now seeing other issues.

Comment: Grrrrrr @anubhava I am ready to toss the whole mod_rewrite thing. I have never had this many issues with trying to do something I thought was relatively simple.

Comment: It is because you are dealing with some broken implementation of `mod_rewrite`

Comment: I just had another conversation with the host and they are promising to check on it @anubhava I am now having a problem *with the same htaccess file shown* in which the url for the CSS and other files get appended to the end of the /content/tagged/ portion of the url, like http://localhost:8080/test/content/tagged/resources/css/site.css ***sigh***

Comment: What is `/test/` after `:8080` when you mentioned everything is placed in `DocumentRoot`?

Comment: On localhost everything is in `/test/` and on the webserver everything is in `DocumentRoot`